# Is there an absolute limit to how much data you can put in mailto: body parameter?

Tags: browser, mailto, limits

Given I'm creating a mailto: hyperlink. Is there a absolute limit to how much data you can put in mailto: body parameter?

Is this browser dependent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe these is a limit to the mailto URI. And I believe that limit is dependent on the browser.

Check out this question and answers: [Getting around mailto / href / url character limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067391/getting-around-mailto-href-url-character-limit)

Like they suggest in that answer, I would suggest doing some sort of server side processing of the data, most likely in a POST over a GET.

Also from that question, this link (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q208427) was presented and  tells that IE has a limit of 2083 characters in a URL.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a max of 8000 chars in a URI defined in some spec somewhere

More than you'll ever need :)

Comment: Not more than I ever need, I'd like to be able to put somewhere around 32-96K in it.

Comment: Sounds like should probably POST that kind of data